# Error when automating type option via xdotool

Tags: shell-script, raspberry-pi, raspbian, xdotool

I want to open Chromium browser and then open a couple of web pages, let's say "google.com", and "stackexchange.com". My code for the same is below.

```
#!/bin/bash
#website 1
chromium-browser
xdotool type http://google.com
xdotool key --delay 2000 'Return'
xdotool key 'ctrl+Tab'

#website 2
xdotool type http://stackexchange.com
xdotool key --delay 2000 'Return'
```

The problem:

1) This piece of code only works when I already have a Chromium browser open. Then only, it opens another Chromium browser (as per the code) and performs everything perfectly.

2) If I don't have a browser already open, then this script just opens the browser and does nothing.

Where am I going wrong? Why do I need to have another browser open for the code to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chromium open the tabs on its own, without needing `xdotool` :

```
chromium-browser http://google.com http://stackexchange.com &
```

Will open a new chromium window (if none was opened before) with 2 tabs

then you can switch between the tabs with `xdotool` with

```
xdotool search --onlyvisible --class "chromium" windowfocus key 'ctrl+Tab'
```

if you want to repeat every 5 seconds :

```
while true ; do sleep 5 ; xdotool key 'ctrl+Tab' ; done
```

Comment: Hello, I have tried this approach too. This opens only the first web page and then stops, not proceeding to the second one. This too only works when I have opened another browser window in the background, then and only then this piece of code seems to work.

Comment: I edited, can you try again ?

Comment: your solution did work to open multiple tabs, but yet again when i want to cycle through them I am getting the same issue, i,e, it is not working. I need to have opened another browser in the background to get anything done. Why is this so? thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'cycle through them" ?

Comment: I want to open a couple of pages and keep moving from one page to another after a span of 5secs (by pressing ctrl+Tab), and keep on doing that. For that, I am using xdotool type option.

Comment: What command do you use to make xdotool focus on the right window ?

Comment: Something like `xdotool search --onlyvisible --class "chromium" windowfocus key 'ctrl+Tab'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73571/discussion-between-pi3-14-and-felicien).